# Por que no imprime go while en codigo Java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente codigo que no me esta imprimiendo "vuelta do"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class repeticion dowhile{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declaracion de variables
    int numero,dia,i;
    String nombre;
    // declarar mi Scanner
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    //ciclo for
    for (i=1 ; i<=20 ; i=i+1){
        System.out.println("vuelta "+i);
    }
    //ciclo while /ciclo mientras que
    i=1;
    while (i<=20){
        System.out.println("vuelta while "+i);
        i=i+1;
    }
    // ciclo do - while / ciclo haga hasta /mientras que
    i=1;
    do {      // se garantiza que por lo menos haga la primera vuelta
        System.out.println("vuelta do "+i);
        i=i+1;  // i++;
    }while(i<=20);
}
```

}

Alguien me puede indicar a que se debe que no lo imprima? los otros dos ciclos (**for** y **while**) si lo hacen.

Gracias

Comment: Si está imprimiendo normal

Comment: Si, el problema que tenia es que la clase repeticion dowhile ya estaba usando "repeticion" en otro clase, reemplace el nombre por solo dowhile e imprimio la repeticion do while.